# Can I use always INSERT ....ON DUPLICATE UPDATE for simple updates/inserts?

Tags: sql, mysql

(MYSQL) Is there any significant performance differences, or other reasons not to use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` sql to update by PK/insert new stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is none.

`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will locate the record and update it just as a simple `UPDATE` would do.

In fact this is just a `UPDATE`, followed by an `INSERT` should the `UPDATE` fail.

`INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` can be a faster alternative to a grouped update (when you have a source table with multiple records per key and want to increment the target table once per record).

If there are few values per key, this query:

```
INSERT
INTO    t_target
SELECT  target, cnt
FROM    t_sparse d
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        t_target.cnt = t_target.cnt + d.cnt
```

will be more efficient than this one:

```
INSERT
INTO    t_target
SELECT  target, cnt
FROM    (
        SELECT  target, SUM(cnt) AS cnt
        FROM    t_sparse di
        GROUP BY
                target
        ) d
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        t_target.cnt = t_target.cnt + d.cnt
```

See this article in my blog for more detail:

- [**Efficient INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/27/efficient-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a more nuanced answer. It depends on the implementation of the DBMS. Nevertheless, from experience I can tell you that most DBMS have some pretty good support for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`.

Actually, it can often lead to better performance to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` since the DMBS can group these commands, resulting in less work to be done. This is the case with mysql and you can often see some 10 to 20% increase in speed compare to a simple insert + update strategy without any kind of batching. Overall I would recommend the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` because it is simpler to use, your code is easier to maintain and it often leads to an additional speed benefit.

Comment: Which are the others DBMSs (except `MySQL`) that support this clause?